# How to set some PHP headers in a .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers

So I have these headers in some of my PHP files:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Style-Type: text/css');
    header('Content-Script-Type: application/javascript');
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    header('Content-language: en-US');
    header('X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17');
    header('Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT');
?>
```

How do I set them in my .htaccess file? (Should be for specific files only), here's what I got so far:

```
<FilesMatch "^(index.php|about.php|contact.php)$">
    # HTTP Headers should be set in here
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Somethings like expires and caching can be defined in .htaccess, but things like HTTP 200 should not be. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The directive has the surprising name of [Header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_headers.html#header) ;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have mod_headers installed, or you might get error 500. You can wrap the setting of headers in a condition to check if mod_headers is present or not.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 2015 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

You can also unset headers. For example, if you're behind a load balacer the real visitor IP could be passed in form of a custom header you don't want to expose to the application.

```
Header unset Real-Visitor-IP
```

Besides expiration and etags, and webserver specific custom headers, you shouldn't tamper with headers at webserver level. Most of them should be managed at the application level, and you would prevent some frameworks from working normally if you pass them altered content types.

Comment: mod_headers is definitely installed on my server. Also these are not all the headers, are they? I just want the PHP script above converted into Apache directives...

Comment: It was just an example. Yes, all those PHP directives you can set with mod_headers, but besides expiration, etags, cache, that's the application job. If you manually set header status to 200, your application won't be able to answer to a simple 404 not found request.

Comment: Alright and what about `Content-Style-Type, Content-Script-Type and Content-language`?

Comment: Those are fallbacks from HTML 4.01 times. I don't think they are useful anymore in modern browsers. Besides, they only made sense when declared on an html document. A stylesheet doesn't need a default Content-Style Type, because it is the style in itself.

Comment: Ahh, the good old DTD-based markup languages... I now use HTML5 but I'd like to keep compability for browsers such as IE 6...